# Pandoc does not create TOC when headers are inside divs with an id

Tags: pandoc

The command

```bash
echo '<div><h1>Title</h1></div>' | pandoc -s -f html -t html --toc
```

gives output

```html
...
<nav id="TOC" role="doc-toc">
<ul>
<li><a href="#title">Title</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
...
```

However, if I add an `id` to the surrounding `div`,

```bash
echo '<div id="asdf"><h1>Title</h1></div>' | pandoc -s -f html -t html --toc
```

no `toc` is created in the output. Is there a way to get around this issue?

I came across this problem while generating a large `html` document from a bunch of `markdown` files. Each input file needs to be preprocessed with a non-standalone template, surrounding the output in a `<div id="{unique-per-file}">` for some javascript to be able to identify each part.

(As an aside, this also feels rather clumsy, so if anyone has a better suggestion than doing

```bash
for s in $sections; do
    pandoc -f markdown -t html --template temps/section.html $s
done | pandoc -f html -t html --template temps/index.html > index.html
```

I would love to hear it.)

I have tried various ways around this, but any time I get pandoc to create a `toc` it seems to also strip away whichever element I use to contain my sections.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. What's your pandoc version as given by `pandoc -v`?

Comment: Good point, I have `pandoc 2.9.2.1`. If you are seeing a table-of-contents or retaining wrapper elements, then maybe a simple upgrade is all I need. Will report back.